# google plus login not working after put a play store in android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I have created google plus signed Apk and after put a play store.Then download the application google plus login not working in android.How to solve this problem

Comment: update your signed keystore sha on developer console

Comment: most probably duplicate of......https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889222/google-sign-in-not-working-on-android?noredirect=1#comment76790827_44889222

Answer (score 0):

Probably your production key and debug key difference, make sure you put both keys in your google-json file and both keys in console.google google+plus api correctly, use gradle build to get the SHA and MD5 correctly