# Android: Login with google and login with facebook is not working

Tags: android, facebook, gmail-api

I have developed one android app and tested this in my cellphone and emulator too. I am using Android Studio.

I have used "Login with Google" & "Login with facebook" features but these features are both working on my device and once my app is published in play store then both these features are not working.

Please help me.

I am sharing manifest.xml details:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="in.gdc4gpat">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:icon" android:largeHeap="true">
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" tools:replace="android:theme" />
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Login" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Welcome" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/Welcome">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".NoNetwork" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Video" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".NotificationView" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".GalleryCategory" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MCQCategory" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MCQSubjects" android:parentActivityName=".MCQCategory" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MCQCategory" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Gallery" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DownloadCategory" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".KYCForm" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".Mnemonics" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Downloads" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Alerts" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AlertDetails" android:parentActivityName=".Alerts" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".Alerts" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Jobs" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".JobDetails" android:parentActivityName=".Jobs" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".Jobs" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Packages" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PackageDetails" android:parentActivityName=".Packages" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".Packages" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Contact" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".News" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewsDetails" android:parentActivityName=".News" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".News" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Course" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CourseDetails" android:parentActivityName=".Course" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".Course" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".PharmaFactSubjects" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Pharmafacts" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".PharmafactsDetails" android:label="@string/app_name" android:parentActivityName=".Pharmafacts" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".Pharmafacts" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Seminar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SeminarDetails" android:label="@string/app_name" android:parentActivityName=".Seminar" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".Seminar" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MCQ" android:label="@string/app_name" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Questions" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!--  ############################ ONLINE EXAM MODULES ###########################  -->
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.DailyQuiz" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.TestDetails" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.TestPackages" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.TestPackages" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.TopicWiseSubjects" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.TestPackages" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.TestPackageDetails" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.StudyMaterial" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.StudyMaterialDetails" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.StudyMaterial" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.StudyMaterial" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Test" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Register" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.ForgotPassword" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.OtpVerification" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/FullScreen">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.ResetPassword" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.StartTest" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/FullScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Profile" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.ProfileEdit" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Profile" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Profile" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.ChangePassword" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Results" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.ScoreCard" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Results" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Results" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Toppers" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Results" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Results" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Answers" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Results" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Results" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Wallet" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.WalletAdd" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Wallet" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Wallet" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Orders" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.MyTest" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Offers" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.CapsuleSubject" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Capsules" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.CapsuleSubject" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.CapsuleSubject" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.CapsuleDetails" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Capsules" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Capsules" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.ShareAndEarn" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.Feedback" android:parentActivityName=".onlineexam.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".onlineexam.Home" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.CheckOut" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!--  ******************* PG *************************   -->
    <activity android:name=".onlineexam.PayNowWeb" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <!--  Firebase Notifications  -->
    <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <!--  ./Firebase Notifications  -->
</application>
```

Comment: "not working" -- in what way??

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946528/google-plus-login-not-working-after-put-a-play-store-in-android), maybe there is an issue with your production key and debug key. Make sure that you put both keys in your google-json file and in console.google. Also, I think you are using the debug keystore sha1 that's why it is working only in debug mode.

Additional references:

- [Google sign in not working after publishing in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store)

  > Release APK and debug APK has different SHA1 and different API keys for google services. Both of them must be added in Firebase Console -> Project settings. Then download `google-services.json` from here, add it to project and recompile with release keystore using option "Build signed APK". That should work
- [android:google login api and facebook log in api cannot use in app apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055827/androidgoogle-login-api-and-facebook-log-in-api-cannot-use-in-app-apk)